# How to print the failed mount points in unix?

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, mount

I have different mountpoints with different names in each Unix servers. Here, we need to have one only script to list out the failed mount point and implement the same in all servers.

Expected as below

```
/dev/mount1 mount point is missing from the host hostname.domain.com
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. What is a "failed mount point". If you just want to check whether or not /dev/mount1 is mounted anywhere, you can use something like "mount | grep '^/dev/mount1 '".

Comment: How do you determine that you have failed mount points at the moment?

Comment: Stackoverfow is dedicated to helping with programming code problems. This seems more like a *nix user issue, which would be more appropriate on https://unix.stackexchange.com or https://superuser.com .  Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: what about checking output of mount command against /etc/fstab?

Answer (score 0):

Please do a "mount -v"(verbose mode) on the terminal, if there is a failed mount point then it will also show up in here. Look for the errors.

Comment: Here the requirement is, the script should display what are the mount points missing in each server. i.e. fstab has entry, we need to compare that with df -h command.